# How many functions from $[0, 1]$ to $[0, 1]$ have a left-sided limit at every point?

Tags: limits, cardinals

How many functions from $[0, 1]$ to $[0, 1]$ have a left-sided limit at every point?
There is at least $|\mathbb{R}|$ of them, since $f(x) = rx, r \in \mathbb{R}$ obviously works. How can I show that there is no more than $|\mathbb{R}|$ of such functions?

Comment: I've added mod signs around $\Bbb R$, since you meant to talk about its cardinality, which is [often denoted](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardinality_of_the_continuum) $\mathfrak{c}$ (`\mathfrak{c}`) or $\beth_1$ (`\beth_1`). As for your question, consider how constraining is the function's behaviour on $[0,\,1]\cap\Bbb Q$.

Comment: @J.G. could you please expand on your idea about constraining? Do you mean something like uniform-continuity?

Comment: @ABlack : I think you mean $f(x)=rx, r \in [0,1]$, or $f(x)=r, r\in [0,1]$. The overall question would be easier if we assumed $f$ was left-continuous everywhere, since then its values everywhere are determined once its values on the rationals are known.

Comment: @Michael would you mind giving more detail on how to approach this if $f$ is left-continuous everywhere? Maybe I could rearrange your argument somehow to work here too.

Comment: @ABlack : That case seems much simpler: (i) Show $|\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{Q}}|=|\mathbb{R}|$; (ii) Show that if $f(x)$ is left-continuous and its values are known for all $x \in \mathbb{Q}$ then there are no further choices for $f(y)$ for $y \notin \mathbb{Q}$ (given $y \notin \mathbb{Q}$, there is one and only one value $f(y)$ that could work). I don't currently see an answer if we only assume $f$ has left-limits: Are you sure there are only $|\mathbb{R}|$ of those functions?

Comment: @ABlack : What is the context of this question (homework/class material?) I think one way to argue for $|\mathbb{R}|$ is to first show there are only $|\mathbb{R}|$ possible left-limit functions $g(x)=\lim_{y\rightarrow x^-}f(x)$, and then show any two functions $f(x), h(x)$ with the same left-limit function $g(x)$ must differ at an at most countable number of points.